# Typescript warnings, exhaustive-deps, useEffect dependency list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've been encountering this problem recently, but never cared to get into it. There is a warning from a Typescript when listing *useEffect* dependencies, very sweet that it understands what I should put as dependencies: `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'radius'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps`.
But why does it throw this error when including both of those deps:
`The 'drawBall' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 41) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'drawBall' in its own useCallback() Hook.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps`, thought since it is in deps list, it is only natural to have it inside of useEffect() itself, but still, couldn't quite understand its logic.

```
export default function Ball({ radius }: BallProps) {
    const ball = new Image()
    ball.src = "/billiard.png"

    const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

    const drawBall: DrawBallProps = (ctx, radius) => {

        // Ball
        ctx.drawImage(ball, 0, 0, radius * 2, radius * 2);
               
        //animate the ball
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        if (!canvas) return;
        
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        if (!ctx) return;

        
        const render = () => {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            drawBall(ctx, radius);
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            console.log('rendered');
        };

        render();
    }, [drawBall, radius]);

    return (
        <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={100} height={100} style={{ border: '1px solid black' }} />
    );
}
```

Does it change anything if I do not include draw function or the radius as dependencies?, yes...I am that bad at this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function is not a primitive it is an object. So every time that the component Ball rerenders the function drawBall re-created. old **drawBall** and new **drawBall** isn't equal. It triggers **useEffect**.

some solutions:

1. remove it of deps of useEffect
2. move it into useEffect (preferable solution in your case)
3. use useCallback hook

   const drawBall: DrawBallProps = useCallback((ctx, radius) => {
   //logic
   }, [radius]);

   useEffect(() => {
   //logic
   }, [drawBall, radius]);